# Limit the length of characters in UITableView's cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have to limit the amount of characters or length of UITableView's cell texts . Because each cell displays a very long long long text and I have to limit these text into for example 140 characters . because it causes slow scrolling and memory issues and etc ...

I am loading cell texts from an SQL DB :

```
    appClass = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    readerClass = (Reader *)[appClass.wordList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text=readerClass.Name;
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you elaborate? and why cant a simple if with yourString.length cant work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
cell.textLabel.text = (readerClass.Name.length > 140 ? [readerClass.Name substringToIndex:140] : readerClass.Name);
```

This sets the full `readerClass.Name` when it has fewer than 140 characters and sets the first 140 characters if it is longer.

Also, I'm assuming you have a UILabel in the UITableViewCell, which automatically appends `...` (ellipsis) when text is truncated. If not, you can add ellipsis yourself:

```
cell.textLabel.text = (readerClass.Name.length > 140 ? [[readerClass.Name substringToIndex:137] stringByAppendingString:@"..."] : readerClass.Name);
```

---

Just at add on to this question, since you asked about getting the first line only:

```
// get first line break range
NSRange rangeOfFirstLineBreak = [cell.textLabel.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
// check if first line break range was found
if (rangeOfFirstLineBreak.location == NSNotFound) {
    // if it was, extract the first line only and update the cell text
    cell.textLabel.text = [cell.textLabel.text substringToIndex:rangeOfFirstLineBreak.location];
}
```

Comment: Glad to be of help! By the way, don't forget to choose an answer, it helps our reps :)

Comment: Yes, I added some sample code to the answer. In cases like this, though, I would encourage you ask a separate question so others who find this one don't get confused.

Comment: There is a little Bug. It should rather be `rangeOfFirstLineBreak.location != NSNotFound`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
NSRange stringRange = {0, MIN([readerClass.Name length], 140)};
cell.textLabel.text = [readerClass.Name substringWithRange:stringRange];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It also adds '...'

```
NSString *name = readerClass.Name;

if( name.length > 140 ){
    name = [place substringToIndex:140];
    name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...", name];
}

cell.textLabel.text= name;
```